# Why do I get a runtime error for this simple thread example?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread th([] { std::cout << "Hello, World\n"; });
    th.join();
}
```

This is all I have and it causes a runtime error. Why is that? I'm using GCC 4.8 (Ideone).

Comment: Can you post the command line arguments? Did you pass `-pthread` to g++?

Comment: @Praetorian Ideone doesn't allow command-line arguments.

Comment: Try something better then, like [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) (although it seems to be having some issues right now :))

Comment: you're missing ()?

`std::thread th([]() { /**/ };);`

Comment: @Chemistpp You don't need the `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error from ideone is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>    what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Which means you need to be compiling with `-pthread` as already suggested by @Praetorian.

The code runs fine in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: But Coliru hasn't been working recently, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Thanks!

Comment: @MemyselfandI: coliru.stacked-crooked.com has problem right now, no program works in it.