# Runtime error for multi-ithreaded access to unordered_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton

I have this multi-threaded code which attempts to create a thread local singleton object using the stl `unordered_map`.

Here is the [code](http://ideone.com/BJN98X). I am reproducing the code here verbatim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

class single
{
public:
    // Every thread needs to call this to get its individual instance
    static single* getInstance( unsigned int threadId );

    static void print( unsigned int threadId )
    {
        std::cout << "threadId:"    << threadId << ", Singleton: " << _instances[threadId] << std::endl;
    }

protected:
    // Made protected not private so that singleton can be subclassed
    single();                                           // Clients cant construct objects directly
    ~single();                                          // cannot be destroyed by clients

    single(const single &) = delete;                    // non-copyable
    single& operator=(const single &) = delete;         // can't be copy assigned
    single(single &&) = delete;                         // non-move constructible
    single & operator=(single && ) = delete;            // non-move assignable

private:
    static std::unordered_map<unsigned,single*> _instances;
    static std::mutex _lock;

};

std::mutex single::_lock;
std::unordered_map<unsigned,single*> single::_instances;

single::single(){}

single::~single(){}

single* single::getInstance( unsigned int threadId )
{
    if( _instances.count( threadId ) == 0 )
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(_lock);
        if( _instances.count( threadId ) == 0 )
        {
            _instances[threadId] = new single;
            std::cout <<"Created By ThreadId: " << threadId <<std::endl;
        }
    }

    return _instances[threadId];
}

void Run( unsigned int threadId )
{
    single::getInstance(threadId)->print(threadId);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    const unsigned threadCount = 16;

    for( auto i = 0; i != threadCount; ++i )
    {
        workers.push_back( std::thread( Run, i ) );
    }

    for_each( workers.begin(), workers.end(), std::mem_fn(&thread::join) );

    return 0;
}
```

I use `unordered_map`'s `count()` constant function (thread safe??) to check if the instance for the thread was created. If the count is 0, I create the instance and store it as value of the key as `threadId`. I also added a `lock_guard` to prevent concurrent insertions by multiple threads to the unordered map static object, but it seems like their is some race condition which I can't spot and this code sometimes gives error.

Can anyone explain to me in which part of this code the race condition is happening and if this solution can be made to work for thread local singletons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me in which part of this code the race condition is happening...

No, it is not thread safe. Once there is at least 1 writer, all access needs to be guarded by the lock. So the first `_instances.count()` is unguarded and can cause a data race.

> ... and if this solution can be made to work for thread local singletons?

You could look to use [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) to control the local thread storage duration.

You could also migrate the lock guard up to before any access on the `unordered_map` is made.

```
single* single::getInstance( unsigned int threadId )
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(_lock);
    if( _instances.count( threadId ) == 0 )
    {
        _instances[threadId] = new single;
        std::cout <<"Created By ThreadId: " << threadId <<std::endl;
    }
    return _instances[threadId];
}
```

[Demo code here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f66d1fdb53ebdc)

---

Side note on the thread count, depending on the problem being solved, you could limit the number of threads to the [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) limit.

Comment: well, I mentioned that count() is a constant function. Is it not thread safe as it only reads and doesnt modify the map  state?

Comment: That `const` means that the `count()` function doesn't change the contents of the container, it doesn't mean that other functions won't change the content at the same time (the data race).

Comment: About your code migration suggestion, I initially did like that. But it wasn't working. So I thought I should try to use double check locking to prevent race condition on _instances.count()

Comment: So basically as I understand there is a race between thread x reading using count and thread y writing to container ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It works here; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52f66d1fdb53ebdc. Do you link with pthread (not sure why it would not have worked earlier)?

Comment: I am using ideone.com. Here is link to copy of your code on ideone: http://ideone.com/hMbYw0

Comment: Ok, I think its a compilation problem with ideone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553484/why-do-i-get-a-runtime-error-for-this-simple-thread-example/19553767#19553767

Comment: So essentially my double check was causing problem and single lock_guard was enough ?

Comment: I think you are correct on the ideone limitation, reducing the thread count seems to get the code to run ok. http://ideone.com/4XMLsE

Comment: Correct, a single lock is enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104639/discussion-between-nurabha-and-niall).